# Is there a tool for modeling what power requirements different satellite modules have?

Tags: geostationary, power

Reading about [FADsat](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324922170_FADSat_A_system_engineering_tool_for_the_conceptual_design_of_geostationary_Earth_orbit_satellites_platform) made me think of this because it does exactly that. Maybe a better question is does anyone know of a tool like FADsat?

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration Stack Exchange! You might want to look for software that's targeted to Cubesat development.